# Add property in class dynamically

Tags: c#, json

I have a list of product class, e.g:

```
{  
   Name = "Product 1",
   Category = "TV",
   Region = "China"
},
{  
   Name = "Product 2",
   Category = "Watch",
   Region = "Germany"
},
{  
   Name = "Product 3",
   Category = "Smartphone",
   Region = "USA"
}
```

and unsorted product price list for every year (in format product, year and amount), e.g:

```
Product 1, 2016, $2000    
Product 2, 2016, $300
Product 1, 2017, $1800
Product 3, 2017, $500
Product 2, 2017, $290
```

I need to display the products with price - to show the comparison of price for every year. The end result should look like this:

```
Name           Category      Year 2016   Year 2017
Product 1      TV              2000        1800
Product 2      Watch            300         290
Product 3      Smartphone        -          500
```

Since the price list will expand every year, therefore I plan to keep a list of string as properties in class.

```
List<string> Headers = new List<string> {
    "Name",
    "Category",
    "Region"
};

foreach (string year in distinctYear)
{
    Headers.Add("Y" + year);
}
```

Until here, I'm stuck, how can I convert them into a class, so that I could assign the value like this:

```
{  
   Name = "Product 1",
   Category = "TV",
   Y2016 = 2000,
   Y2017 = 1800
},
{  
   Name = "Product 2",
   Category = "Watch",
   Region = "Germany",
   Y2016 = 300,
   Y2017 = 290
},
{  
   Name = "Product 3",
   Category = "Smartphone",
   Region = "USA",
   Y2017 = 500
}
```

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: What about having `Dictionary<int, decimal>` to store information on each year price instead of dozens `Yxxx` properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combine both `ProductList` and `PriceList` classes into a dictionary:

```
foreach (var item in ProductList)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    dict["Name"] = item.Name;
    dict["Category"] = item.Category;
    dict["Region"] = item.Region;
    foreach (var i in item.PriceList)
    {
        dict[i.Year] = i.Amount;
    }
    list.Add(dict);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary where the key is the year and the value is the price.

```
class Product
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
            public string Region { get; set; }
            public IDictionary<int, decimal> PricePerYear { get; set; } 
                = new Dictionary<int, decimal>( );
        }

var prod = new Product
                   {
                       Name = "Product1",
                       Category = "TV",
                       Region = "China",
                   };
        prod.PricePerYear.Add( 2016, 2000 );
        prod.PricePerYear.Add( 2017, 4500 );
```

OR (C#7)
Lets use some Tuples! As per Chris's comment you can also initialize the list/dictionary during creation.

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public IList<(int year, decimal amount)> PricePerYear { get; set; }
}


 var prod = new Product
                       {
                           Name = "Product1",
                           Category = "TV",
                           Region = "China",
                           PricePerYear = new List<(int year, decimal amount)>
                                          {
                                              (year: 2016, amount: 5000),
                                              (2017, 10000),
                                              (2018, 5000),
                                          }
                       };

            (int year, decimal price) = prod.PricePerYear.First( );
            Console.WriteLine( $"Year: {year} Price: {price}" );
            Console.ReadLine( );
```

Comment: In case you are unaware you could have populated the dictionary in the initializer as well with `PricePerYear = {{2016,2000},{2017,4500}}`. Not sure if you did it outside for readability or because you were unaware.

Comment: Readability. Wanted to show how you might add values after initialization.

Comment: Ah well. I'm sure somebody will come along who isn't aware so my comment might be useful for them. ;-)

Comment: hi @WBuck, the result I get when serialize object into Json is `[{"Name":"Product1","Category":"TV","Region":"China","PricePerYear":{"2016":2000,"2017":1800}}]` instead of what I need is `[{"Name":"Product1","Category":"TV","Region":"China","2016":2000,"2017":1800}]` because with this format, it could adapt into kendoGrid -> datasource easily..

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list to store the prices; for example using these two classes:

```
    class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public List<Price> Prices { get; set; }
    }

    class Price
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can initialize an instance of Product as follows:

```
    Product prod1 = new Product()
    {
        Name = "Product1",
        Category = "TV",
        Region = "China",
        Prices = new List<Price>()
        {
            new Price()
            {
                Year = 2016,
                Amount = 2000
            },
            new Price()
            {
                Year = 2017,
                Amount = 1800
            }
        }
    };
```